# Assigning Ranks to strings and creating new column in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a ratings projects. These are the ratings (AA, A, BB, B, C). AA is the highest ranking and C is the worst.
This is the sample data frame

| Company | Old_rating | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MICRO | A | 1 |
| AMD | C | 2 |
| NVID | BB | 0 |
| FB | A | -2 |
| TWT | None | NA |

A rating change of +1 indicates moving from a lower grade to higher grade (for e.g. A to AA). Similar changes for other numbers. I want to create a new column (New_Rating) based on these calculations

required output

| Company | Old_rating | Change | New_Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MICRO | A | 1 | AA |
| AMD | C | 2 | BB |
| NVID | BB | 0 | BB |
| FB | A | -2 | B |
| TWT | None | NA | B |

I am new to python. How can I carry out this operation in Python?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"Company":"MICRO","Old_rating":"A","Change":1},
        {"Company":"AMD", "Old_rating":"C", "Change":2},
        {"Company":"NVID", "Old_rating":"BB", "Change":0},
        {"Company":"FB", "Old_rating":"A", "Change":-2}]


ratings = ["AA","A","BB","B","CC","C"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df["New_rating"] = df.apply(lambda row: ratings[min(max(ratings.index(row["Old_rating"])-row["Change"],0),len(ratings)-1)], axis=1)

  Company Old_rating  Change New_rating
0   MICRO          A       1         AA
1     AMD          C       2          B
2    NVID         BB       0         BB
3      FB          A      -2          B
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary with ranks, e.g.:
mapDict={'A':1, 'AA':2, 'B':3....}

Then:

```
df['New_Rating']=pd.DataFrame(df['Change']+df['Old_rating'].replace(mapDict)).replace(mapDict)
```

*df['Old_rating'].replace(mapDict)* - Convert old ratings into corresponding numbers.

*df['Change']+df['Old_rating'].replace(mapDict)* - Add the numerical Change values.

*pd.DataFrame* - Wraps the above as a Pandas DataFrame object so we can use the *replace* method again to convert back into string rankings.

**You probably want to limit the change to the possible ranks**
Assuming your numerical ranks go from 0 to 10:

```
df['New_Rating']=pd.DataFrame(df['Change']+df['Old_rating'].replace(mapDict)).clip(0,10).replace(mapDict)
```

Here the *clip* method makes sure all values will be in range, and if they are not - they are "clipped".

Comment: It gives an error- Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'. I think the final conversion would be an issue. But, I can work around it. Thanks

Comment: @GreenFinance It works perfectly fine with the example data you provided, unless the numeric column is actually string. What code did you end up using that gives you this error?